# Given a ordered sequence of real numbers, show that: $\sum_{i = 1}^{k} a_{i}^{2} / k \leq \sum_{i = 1}^{n} a_{i}^{2} / n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality, real-numbers

Given a ordered sequence of real numbers $A = \left \{a_{1}, a_{2}, ... a_{n} \right\}$ such that $a_{i} \leq a_{j}$ for $i < j$, show that:
$\sum_{i = 1}^{k} a_{i}^{2} / k \leq \sum_{i = 1}^{n} a_{i}^{2} / n$

I recently came across a proof in a paper that made use of this inequality. While I think I can sense why this is true, I was unable to make much headway with regards to providing a rigorous proof. I've tried applying induction and AM-GM inequality, but I'm not sure if they can be used in proving this inequality. Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In other words, cumulative averages of an increasing sequence are increasing, which indeed is hard to deny.

Rearranging, it is equivalent that

$$n \sum_1^k a_i^2 \leq k \sum_1^n a_i^2,$$

or

$$(n-k) \sum_1^k a_i^2 \leq k \sum_{k+1}^n a_i^2,$$

or

$$ \frac1k \sum_1^k a_i^2 \leq \frac1{n-k} \sum_{k+1}^n a_i^2.$$

This is clear, because LHS is $\leq a_k^2$ and RHS is $\geq a_{k+1}^2$.

Comment: Yikes, why didn't I think about putting the numbers back in the denominator after musing over the second step? Thanks @Sean Eberhard for the help!